# Linker Error (undefined reference to 'function')?

Tags: c++, linker

I'm new to C++, and I attempted to compile a program when I received the error message

```
undefined reference to '(lengthy void function name)'
```

After reading around a bit, I think my program has what is called a linker error (correct me if I'm wrong). I am not using any headers in this program, and my function prototype, function call (in main), and my function definition all have the same variables within the parenthesis. I was under the impression that these errors mainly result from typos, but after poring over the code, I don't think that's the case here. What are the other causes of linker errors (in terms a newbie could understand, please)?

Comment: If you post your code, you are more likely to get help.

Comment: If you are programming in c++, then typos should typically result in compiler errors and not linker errors. Linker errors are mostly caused by not linking to the correct libraries/object-files or forgetting to implement the specific functions.

Comment: It generally means you either misspelled `length` `lengthy` somewhere in your code, or you are using a function say `lengthy (foo)` and you either haven't included the header, are using it before it is defined, forgot to link the library or your forgot to define `lengthy (foo)` altogether.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I apologize for my lack of correct formatting, but thanks to those of you who provided input. The problem is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, it's almost impossible to tell what the problem could be, however, if I had to guess, it's possible you defined your function after main, and so main can't access it. Eg:

```
int main()
{
    //Call to lengthy void function
}

void lengthyFunction()
{
    //code
}
```

just cut and paste your function definition to before main:

```
void lengthyFunction()
{
    //code
}

int main()
{
    //call to lengthy void function
}
```